# Do you need to push the code before doing git pull?

Tags: github

I was trying to push some files. But do I need to use git pull before pushing files to Git?

Comment: yes, if the remote branch has newer commits that you don't yet have locally, you need to pull before pushing. (unless you force-push, that is)

Answer (score 0):

https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/saving-changes

No, you don't *need* to git pull before git push, ***but if you are working with a team***, by doing git pull it means that your local branch will rebase and try to be the same as your remote one. By pulling first you are making sure that you have the latest commits on your local and avoid as much as possible any merge conflicts.

I usually do

```
git pull 
git add <file>
git push
```

Comment: "by doing git pull it means that your local branch will rebase" - the default action is merge. You probably can configure it to rebase on pulls, but I personally never needed that.

Comment: If your local branch is not up-to-date with the remote, git will reject your push. That is also when the merge conflicts happen, on pull (which is a combination of fetch/merge). So you _do_ need to pull if the remote has commits you don't have.